# jqPlot "stacked" y-axis

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying to code a widget to display financial charts like [this one](http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=%24SPX&p=D&b=5&g=0&id=p70349335506). I would like to know if jqPlot offers a native way of stacking different y-axis with the same x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Jqplot provide different y-axis with the same x-axis.

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/1481/)

like this

```
 axes:{
          xaxis:{
              min:0           
          },
          yaxis:{  
            autoscale:true,
            label: "hello"
          },  
          y2axis:{
            autoscale:true, 
            tickOptions:{showGridline:false},
            label: "Hi"
          }

      }
```

Comment: I know that several axis can be used, but not in the way I want. I need them to use different regions, as shown in the link I provided.